# Unsupported operand types from concatenation in PHP codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, concatenation, operands

So I have this error, "Unsupported operand types", coming from a concatenation in a PHP code. Below is the specific line where the error occurs:

```
  'full_name'  => ($recipient['firstname'].' '.$recipient['lastname'])
```

The snippet is from an array container shown as below:

```
  $summary = array(
   'full_name'  => ($recipient['firstname'].' '.$recipient['lastname'])
 );
```

There's nothing wrong with my code but it still produces this error. It was working before and then when I tried to test it again without changing anything, the error appeared.

I am currently using, Codeigniter for the framework.

**[UPDATED] Below is the function's code until where the error occured:**

public function index_post() {
        // set max execution time and time limit to prevent time out because of the 3rd party integrations
        ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
        set_time_limit ( 300 );

```
    // get JSON value post request
    $inputJSON      = file_get_contents( 'php://input' );
    $input_post     = json_decode( $inputJSON, TRUE ); //convert JSON into array

    // verify points if it still enough
    $is_points_enough = $this->verify_member_current_pondo_points($input_post['total_points_to_use']);

    // check if member has enough status. if not, return the error code
    if ( !$is_points_enough['status'] ) {
        $this->response( array(
            'status'   => TRUE,
            'response' => $is_points_enough,
        ), REST_Controller::HTTP_OK );
    }

    // construct data to pass to order verification
    $order_data['items']                            = $input_post['purchase_items']; // items to be redeemed
    $order_data['item_redeem_info']     = $input_post['item_redeem_info']; // information of the redeemer
    $order_data['member_info']              = array( // member account id and email from verifying token
        'account' => $this->user->account_id,
        'email'   => $this->user->email
    ); 

    // check if stocks are enough to continue the process
    $order = $this->order_transaction->checkout_order( $order_data ); 

    // if order process failed, it will return an error with its specific error message
    if (!$order['status']) {
        $this->response( array(
            'status'   => TRUE,
            'response' => $order,
        ), REST_Controller::HTTP_OK );
    }
    else {
        $items = $order; // these are the list of items already checked

        $recipient = $order_data['item_redeem_info']; // information of the redeemer
        $recipient_address = $order_data['item_redeem_info']['address']; // address of the redeemer

        $delivery_data['recipients'] = array();
        $recipient_data = array(
            'recipient' => array( // recipient's information
      'firstname'    => $recipient['firstname'],
      'lastname'     => $recipient['lastname'],
      'middlename'   => "",
      'contact'      => $recipient['contact'],
      'email'        => $recipient['email'],
      'notification' => 1, // value 1 means notification on
      'address'      => array(
        'country'     => "PH",
        'destination' => $recipient_address['destination'],
        'province'    => $recipient_address['province'],
        'city'        => $recipient_address['city'],
        'barangay'    => $recipient_address['barangay'],
        'street'      => $recipient_address['street'],
                    'landmarks'   => $recipient_address['landmarks']
                )
            )
        );
        array_push($delivery_data['recipients'], $recipient_data);

        // if order has physical items included
        if (count($items['physical_item'][0]) > 0) {

            $address = array( //address of recipient
      'province' => $recipient_address['province'],
      'city'     => $recipient_address['city'],
      'barangay' => $recipient_address['barangay'],
      'street'   => $recipient_address['street']
            );

            // if type is delivery, insert address data
            if ( ($recipient['type'] == "delivery") ) { 
                $address = $this->order_transaction->add_address( $address );
            } else {
                $address = $this->order_transaction->get_branch_address_id( $recipient['branch'] );
            }

            $_items = $items['physical_item']; //physical items list from the order result
            $_recipients = $delivery_data['recipients'][0]['recipient'];
            $packages['packages'] = array();
            $items_for_summary = array();
            $total_item_quantity = 0;
            $item_details = array();

            // set delivery details - package; also set the item summary to be delivered
            for ( $x = 0; $x < count( $_items ); $x++ ) {
                $result = $this->order_transaction->get_product_data_by_id( $_items[ $x ]['purchase_id'] ); //get product data to populate important details
                array_push( $item_details, $result );

                $_package = array(
                    'package' => array(
                        'pouch'       => 'UL',
                        'description' => $result->name,
                        'weight'      => 0,
                        'width'       => 0,
                        'height'      => 0,
                        'length'      => 0,
                        'value'       => 0,
                        'coupon'      => 0,
                        'sfc'         => 0,
                        'reference'   => "",
                        'notes'       => ""
                    )
                );
                //this container is for the delivery information
                array_push( $packages['packages'], $_package ); 

                //needed for product shipment information
                $total_item_quantity = $total_item_quantity + $_items[ $x ]['quantity']; 
            }

            $delivery_data['recipients'][0]['recipient']['packages'] = $packages['packages'];

            //verify pondo account points if it is enough
            $is_points_enough = $this->verify_member_current_pondo_points( $input_post['total_points_to_use'] );

            // if points is not enough
            if ( !$is_points_enough['status'] ) { 
                $data['status'] = $is_points_enough;
                $data['error'] = array(
                    'code'    => $this->error_code['E_NOT_ENOUGH_POINTS'],
                    'message' => "Not enough points."
                );
                $this->response( array(
                    'status'   => TRUE,
                    'response' => $data,
                ), REST_Controller::HTTP_OK );
            }
            // if points if enough
            else {
                // points to redeem in pondo
                $redeem_data['points'] = $input_post['total_points_to_use']; 
                // description of redeem info for pondo
                $redeem_data['description'] = "Mineski Infinity item/airtime redeem"; 
                // redeem pondo points
                $is_redeem = $this->redeem_current_pondo_points( $redeem_data ); 

                // if it failed to redeem points
                if ( !$is_redeem ) {
                    $data['status'] = FALSE;
                    $data['error'] = array(
                        'code'    => $this->error_code['E_CANNOT_REDEEM'],
                        'message' => "Cannot redeem points."
                    );
                    $this->response( array(
                        'status'   => TRUE,
                        'response' => $data,
                    ), REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST );
                } 
                // if it successfully to redeem points
                else {
                    $delivery_data['schedule'] = $this->_get_delivery_date(); //delivery date
                    //send delivery information to xend
                    $booking_info = $this->order_transaction->ship_items( $delivery_data ); 

                    $booking_info = json_decode( $booking_info );
                    $tracking_code = $booking_info->tracking;

                    // $this->order_transaction->empty_cart( $this->user->id ); //empty cart

                    echo gettype($recipient['firstname']);
                    echo gettype($recipient['lastname']);

                    //set data for product shipment information
                    $summary = array( 
          'full_name'             => ($recipient['firstname'].' '.$recipient['lastname']),
          // 'contact'               => $recipient['contact'],
          // 'email'                 => $recipient['email'],
          // 'address_id'            => $address->id,
          // 'branch_id'             => ($recipient-['type'] == "pickup") ? $recipient['branch'] : '',
          // 'shipment_type'         => $recipient['type'],
          // 'total_item_quantity'   => $total_item_quantity,
          // 'member_id'             => $this->user->id,
          // 'date_ordered'          => date( "Y-m-d h:i:s" ),
          // 'tracking_code'         => $tracking_code[0],
          // 'date_received'         => 0,
          // 'delivery_status'       => 'pending',
          // 'date_expected_arrival' => 0,
          // 'remarks'               => (($recipient['remarks'] == NULL) || ($recipient['remarks'] == "")) ? "" : $recipient['remarks']
                    );

                    print_r($summary);
```

Comment: please provide a `print_r($recipient);`

Comment: @Alex

Array
(
    [full_name] => First Second
)

Comment: Now I'm a bit confused. This looks like the output of $summary... which shouldn't be working as you have the error... shouldn't recipient contain `firstname` and `lastname` keys?

Comment: Yes. I'm really confused too cause it seems no problem at all. The $recipient value has firstname and lastname.

Comment: Can you paste all your code for this particular function as an edit to the question or on pastebin?

Comment: The function consists of 280++ lines. But I will edit it.

Comment: @Alex hello. I already updated it. :D

Comment: yikes 280 plus lines in one function? you should really separate it out to be more manageable. I can't really see where the issue might be. as long as the two variables you are trying to "add" together are strings it shouldn't be an issue. and by your gettype cmd I assume that is already the case  otherwise you'd have  found your error by now. are you 100% sure its that line?

Comment: I will break it down though. Don't worry. Haha. And I am really sure that the error line points to the snippet stated as above. It is really weird. But I will break it down first then I'll let you know after. Thank yoooooooooooouu! <3

Comment: So what is the result of your two `echo gettype` statements? What do you get when you `var_dump` both of those `$recipient` entries?